# What's the best way to show multiple subplots of data that have the same x and y labels? (matplotlib)

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have two subplots I'd like to show horizontally. The x and y axis labels are exactly the same for both plots, even though the ticks are different. What is the most concise way I can plot them horizontally?

Plot 1:

[image]

Plot 2:
[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can check [Sharing axis limits and views](http://matplotlib.sourceforge.net/users/recipes.html).
Other specific examples are found [here](http://matplotlib.sourceforge.net/examples/pylab_examples/shared_axis_across_figures.html) and [here](http://matplotlib.sourceforge.net/examples/pylab_examples/shared_axis_demo.html).
In the first link you will find an example of plots side by side. The other two examples the subplots are in a column but it is trivial to set them horizontally